# Represent Free Tree to Binary Tree

Tags: data-structures, tree

This exercise is from the book ["algorithms in c++"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201350882). Suppose that there is a free tree like this
[image]

First Question: Could we represent this free tree as a binary tree?

> I think that we cannot represent this free tree as a binary tree
>   because there are some nodes that have more than 2 children.

Second Question: How many ordered trees could we represent from this free tree?

> I cannot understand the question. There aren't keys in the nodes in order to decide how to create an ordered tree.

Comment: You can represent a tree that has any number of nodes per child as a [Left child right sibling binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-child_right-sibling_binary_tree). So the existence of some nodes with more than two children is not a reason for rejecting binary tree as a representation of your free tree.

Comment: The second question, I believe, asks how many different trees you could make by starting with the free tree, then adding a directionality to the edges such that the resulting tree is a directed rooted tree.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I didn't know about the Left-child right-sibling binary tree. For the second question, I must create ordered trees not unordered trees (rooted trees).

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question correctly, the task is that of representing a tree as a binary tree, i.e. to use a data structure for binary trees to represent arbitrary trees. Speaking more structurally, the question demands for a method to injectively map arbitrary trees to binary trees.

The technique is described [here](https://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/binaryTreeRepofTree.html); the basic idea is to represent the children `c_1,...c_n`of a node `a`, which may be more than two, by an arbitrarily chosen child, say `c_1`, which becomes the left child of `a`. As the right child of `c_1`, the next child, `c_2` is stored; and so on. This means that for each node, one child is stored in the left subtree, while in the right subtree by chosing always the right child, the 'siblings' of 'alternatives' of the child are stored. The approach can be sketched as follows. Please bear with me for the relatively poor textual representation.

```
arbitrary tree

       a
   /  | |   \
c_1 c_2 c_3 c-4

binary tree

    a
   /
 c_1
    \
    c_2
       \
       c_3
          \
          c_4
```